# How to add a sub context in Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular

I have a simple Angular 5 application.
And it runs on URL http://localhost:4002

I would like to use an additional sub-context. For example http://localhost:4002/myapp

I am not sure where to add this to my local environment.

I tried the below but did not work.

```
<base href="/myapp">
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"did not work"*?

Comment: I mean it works for everything localhost:4200 and also for anything we give after that localhost:4200/xyz

Answer (score 1):

You can create a routing-module and redirect / to /myapp
ex:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import MyAppComponent from './my-app.component.ts'

 const routes: Routes = [
{ path '', redirectTo: 'myapp', pathMatch: full },
{ path 'myapp', component: MyAppComponent }
]
// also add the module to the imports array ex:
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
]
```

Comment: Many thanks mate. I managed to fix it by add extra options to ng build command.  ng build --prod --bh /myapp/ --d /myapp/

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command to fix my issue

```
ng build --prod --bh /myapp/ --d /myapp/
```